# How to select NOT using SQL JOIN

Tags: sql

My question is to select pilots that are currently not assigned to any flight.

My idea is to use `LEFT JOIN` to select pilots that are currently assigned to flights, then select the `null` values. Am I right?

I am trying to select the `null` value by using `WHERE...IS NULL`, but I don't know how. Thanks for the help.

There are five tables:

- Flight:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (route) REFERENCES Route (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (aircraft) REFERENCES Aircraft (id)
  ```
- Aircraft:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (aircraftType) REFERENCES AircraftType (id)
  ```
- AircraftType:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ```
- Pilot:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (person, forAircraftType),
  FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES Person (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (forAircraftType) REFERENCES AircraftType (id)
  ```
- Person:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ```

Here is my code, I can select pilots that are currently assigned to flight

```
SELECT name 
FROM Flight
LEFT JOIN Aircraft     ON Flight.aircraft       = Aircraft.id
LEFT JOIN AircraftType ON Aircraft.AircraftType = AircraftType.id
LEFT JOIN Pilot        ON AircraftType.id       = Pilot.forAircraftType
LEFT JOIN Person       ON Pilot.person          = Person.id
```

Comment: Or any other way to do this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to join your "Flight" table into the query, simply check if the pilot exists in the Flight table:

```
SELECT name 
FROM Aircraft 
LEFT JOIN AircraftType 
ON Aircraft.AircraftType = AircraftType.id
LEFT JOIN Pilot
ON AircraftType.id = Pilot.forAircraftType
LEFT JOIN Person
ON Pilot.person = Person.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Flight WHERE Flight.aircraft = Aircraft.id)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your query or use Right Join as opposed to Left. In its current configuration, Flight is your base table that all other tables are being joined to so it will only return records where pilots have been assinged to a flight i.e. this acts a filter which excludes unassigned Pilots.

By making Pilot or Person as your base, you are aligning all other tables to it and can simply use IS NULL to get your results.

```
SELECT name 

FROM Person 

LEFT JOIN Pilot ON Person.id = Pilot.person
LEFT JOIN AircraftType ON Pilot.forAircraftType = AircraftType.id
LEFT JOIN Aircraft ON AircraftType.id = Aircraft.AircraftType
LEFT JOIN Flight ON Aircraft.id = Flight.aircraft

Where Flight.aircraft IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to select those rows which are contains null into name field of flight

```
SELECT name 
FROM Flight
LEFT OUTER JOIN Aircraft 
ON Flight.aircraft = Aircraft.id
LEFT JOIN AircraftType 
ON Aircraft.AircraftType = AircraftType.id
LEFT JOIN Pilot
ON AircraftType.id = Pilot.forAircraftType
LEFT JOIN Person
ON Pilot.person = Person.id
WHERE Flight.name is null
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to say there is no "name" in Flight table. The only way to find "name" is going to Person table.

Comment: then use a col of flight such as WHERE Flight.id is null

Comment: Thanks you for your time